# In Grails, how can I render a list view as a Jasper report?

Tags: grails, jasper-reports, report, reporting

I am using Grails 2.0.4 and have installed [the Grails Jasper Reports plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/jasper). There is a nice “step-by-step” guide on the plugin page, but it does not seem to cover what I am looking for; I need to basically render a list view using Jasper Reports, and I cannot find anywhere how I might structure a .jrxml file to be used in such a case nor how I should have it rendered (using the `<g:jasperReport>` tag or anything else).

The question, simply put, is this: How can I render the data that I see in my Grails list view through a Jasper report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a Jasper Report (.jrxml) for that and feed that report the params you used to construct the data in the list view. Your Jasper Report file will have to contain the sql query that creates the list and uses the params you provide.

Comment: An (ancient) example that I finally found: http://ironicprogrammer.blogspot.com/2009/09/creating-jasper-reports-in-grails.html. The sample code includes the report file, which was what I most wanted to see.